# Swift toolchain location on Fedora

Tags: swift, linux, fedora, clion

I am trying to set up CLion to work with Swift on Fedora 32. The Swift plugin asks for a toolchain path.

I have installed Swift through `swift-lang` package. Running `which swift` returns `/usr/bin/swift`.

This is a symbolic link to `/usr/libexec/swift/bin/swift` which is the actual executable. Neither `/usr/bin/swift` nor `/usr/libexec/swift/bin/swift` seem to be the toolchain paths that CLion wants.

Any sort of help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and I've managed to figure it out! Basically, you need to create a `usr` folder under `/usr/libexec/swift/` and `mv` all the original folders like `bin`, `local`, `share`, etc. to the new `usr` folder. Remember to recreate the symbolic links for `swiftc` and `swift` inside `/usr/bin/`.

*Longer version:*

Based on the comment by Cgarcia E88 [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000200464/comments/360000462499):

> Apparently the path you choose must contain the folder `usr` underneath,  so in you(r) case it should be just `/` but in general if swift is located at `SOME_PATH/usr/bin/swift` then you must select `SOME_PATH`.

After learning more about what a Swift toolchain folder looks like [here](https://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2018/10/11/dealing-with-a-swift-toolchain/), I am pretty sure that the `/usr/libexec/swift/` is supposed to be the toolchain folder, albeit missing some required folder structure. By default it is:

```
/usr/libexec/swift
├── bin
│   ├── swift
│   └── ...
├── include
├── lib
├── local
└── share
```

While it should be:

```
/usr/libexec/swift
└── usr
    ├── bin
    │   ├── swift
    │   └── ...
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    ├── local
    └── share
```

Comment: Although I'm no longer working on that anymore as I'm using an Apple device for Swift development, I tried your answer just in case. It works!!! Thank you so much for taking your time and replying.

Comment: thank you, your solution helped me.